# VBA looping through range and sorting onto separate spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, sorting, range

I currently have a loop that looks at a variance between two columns  and if the variance is above a certain threshold it then copies to a separate sheet. As of now, the loop works perfectly.

Sheet1

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fruits | 400 | 200 |
| Veggies | 450 | 50 |
| Produce | 100 | 50 |
| Clean | 1000 | 100 |

Code similar to what I am using:

```
Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
Set Sheet1 = Sheet1
Set Sheet2 = Sheet2
J = 2

lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To lastRow

    If B - C  >= 200  Then

    Sheet2.Range("A" & J).Value = Format(J - 2, "000") + 1
    Sheet2.Range("B" & J).Value = Sheet1.Range("A" & i)
    Sheet2.Range("C" & J).Value = Sheet1.Range("B" & i)
    Sheet2.Range("D" & J).Value = Sheet1.Range("C" & i)
    Sheet2.Range("E" & J).Value = Sheet2.Range("C" & i).Value - Sheet2.Range("D" & i).Value

    J = J + 1

    End If

Next i
```

Sheet2 Loop results

| A Count | B Type | C 2020 | D 2021 | E 2020 -2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fruits | 400 | 200 | 200 |
| 2 | Veggies | 450 | 50 | 400 |
| 3 | Clean | 1000 | 100 | 900 |

However, I would like to sort the loop sheet2 results for column E in descending order to look like the below. Can anyone provide the best method to sort the loop results?

Sheet2 Loop results with a descending sort

| A Count | B Type | C 2020 | D 2021 | **E 2020 -2021** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Clean | 1000 | 100 | **900** |
| 2 | Veggies | 450 | 50 | **400** |
| 3 | Fruits | 400 | 200 | **200** |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this below your routine in you posted code.

(note corrected sheet).

```
With Sheet2.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("E:E") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SetRange Range("A:E")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Note I corrected a bug that had the wrong sheet2.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get the sort going by plugging in my counter and placing this outside the routine like you mentioned.